# How to downgrade an iOS app for iPod touch?

Tags: applications, ios, ios-appstore

Is it possible to downgrade an app from a newer version to an older version without having a copy of the older verion.

I guess this could also be rephrased to, 'is it possible to download an older version of an app from the AppStore after the new version has been released'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a word? Nope.

The app store provides a couple of facilities for getting applications, but all of them are for the most recent versions. There's a chance that you may be able to use un-delete software on your iTunes App directory and recover it, if the data space has not already been overwritten. Otherwise, you must preserve IPA's that iTunes throws into the Trash, else they're pretty much gone forever.

Additionally, to the best of my knowledge, IPA binaries are unique on a downloaded system, for DRM purposes, so I *believe* you cannot simply obtain an archived version from a friend, and send it back into iTunes.

Comment: Perhaps a copy from a friend might work if you have indeed purchased it though. What app are you looking for? I'll see if I have it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Time machine enabled or you don't empty your trash very often you're in luck. You can go into Time machine and simply roll back to an older version of the app in Finder. Then if you uninstall and reinstall the app from iTunes you'll get the older version. Apps are stored by default in `/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications` if I'm not mistaken. Just find the older version in your trash or hit Time machine once you get to that directory and roll right on back.